# .xlam add-in does not work on other computers giving two workbooks with the same name error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I created 2 simple macros just to delete some columns and sort the data on Excel. It does not open a file, just works on the active workbook. I saved the macros as .xlam add-in to distribute other team mates.

I also created a custom Ribbon menu. In the ribbon menu I created 2 buttons and assigned my macros one by one. Now, on my computer, when I click on the button in the Ribbon menu, it calls the macro and the macro works perfectly.

When I add the same add-in to my friends' computers it imports the add-in succesfully. It creates a local copy under Add-In file as well.

When it comes to run the macros, however, it gives the following error ""Sorry, excel can't open two of the same workbooks at the same time".

No need to say there is not 2 workbooks with the same name, there is even no other workbooks opened. What could be the problem? Since it is not code related (at least it seems like) I don't share any code here. If you want I can, however, I receive the error as soon as I click on the button in the ribbon menu on my friends' computers. (FYI I created ribbon menu at my friends' computers as well.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *"It creates a local copy under Add-In file as well."* Are you sure the buttons are linked to the macros in that copy? Otherwise it would load the "copy under Add-In" at startup of Excel and the button will try to open another file. Make sure the file exists only once on the computer.

Comment: Thank you very much Pᴇʜ! Couldn't be more to the point. Solved. Appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing all of the menu items associated with the add-in (do so by customizing the ribbon) and then rebuilding the menu items.  In my situation the location of the add-in changed resulting in a path issue.